# "Where does this hash comes from" / Member since today

Tags: discussion, tags

So, I'm pretty sure we all have been trough one of most typical questions
*"Where does this hash comes from?" & Member since today*

Why is there so much interest in this? Can we have a tag called `hash-origin` or something alike?

Or is wrong to answer this? Most of the times these kind of questions are down voted/put on hold.

Isn't there a Wiki type of answer? The "Answer your own question" to give the all the *"Member since today"* a place to look for first? With all the basics of hashes like if it ends in `=` it may be Base64 or it can also be X or Y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason these questions should be closed and not answered, is that is an extremely particular question - i.e. the answers to this question will never, ever help anybody else, since the hash would always be different (unless its something super common, like `MD5('123456')`...).
Also, challenging a community to try and guess, brute force, or reverse engineer some arbitrary value which is *designed* to be impossible to do so, is pointless and counter-productive. Furthermore if you don't know how it was generated, odds are you shouldn't be trying to crack it, and involving strangers on the internet might be implicating them in a possibly illegal act.

Instead, we propose you close it as duplicate of this question:

> [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/33)

(several dozen of this type of question have already been done so... :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the fact that we are [not a free malware analysis service](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/are-we-a-free-malware-analysis-service), there is most likely a consensus that we are also not a free hash analysis service. The analogous argument is that the answer will be only relevant to that particular user and there is an infinite amount of "unknown sequences" that users might submit. Also, it's quite possible that they are just dealing with a random string that will remain unsolved forever.

<s>I think a canonical question for this (maybe "How do I analyze an unknown string?") would be a great idea. I've been thinking about that myself, too.</s>

As @AviD pointed out there is already [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used) question that makes a good duplicate.